# How to fix "Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value" while using tableview.reloaddata

Tags: swift, macos

I'm creating an app where I use a `NSOpenPanel`, linked to a File --> Open... menu. When the user select a .txt file, the program reads it, add the values to an existing array of strings and then SHOULD reload the data in the `TableView`. But when I call the `tableview.reloaddata()`, at run time, it give me the following error: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value`.

Here the code of my `AppDelegate.swift` file:

```
import Cocoa

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    let vc = ViewController(nibName: "ViewController", bundle: nil)

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }

    func applicationShouldTerminateAfterLastWindowClosed(_ sender: NSApplication) -> Bool {
    return true
    }

    @IBAction func openUnFichier(_ sender: NSMenuItem) {
        let fichierPanel: NSOpenPanel = NSOpenPanel()
        fichierPanel.allowsMultipleSelection = false
        fichierPanel.canChooseFiles = true
        fichierPanel.canChooseDirectories = false
        fichierPanel.allowedFileTypes = ["txt"]
        let response = fichierPanel.runModal()
        if response == NSApplication.ModalResponse.OK{
            guard let selectedURL = fichierPanel.url else{return}
            do{
                var fullDocument = try String(contentsOf: selectedURL, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
                print(type(of: fullDocument))
                var lines : [String] = fullDocument.components(separatedBy: "\n" as String)
                for line in lines {
                    vc.test_data.append(line)
                    print(type(of: vc.test_data))
                }
                } catch let error as NSError{
                    print("Erreur!!!!!!! \(error)")
                }
            vc.tableView.reloadData() //IT CRASHES HERE
         }else {

        }
    }
 }
```

And here is the code of my `ViewController.swift`:

```
import Cocoa
import WebKit

class ViewController: NSViewController, NSTableViewDataSource{

    public var test_data = ["https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0AQFQMeOAig", "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=domoD_w3uFw"]
    var test_text = ""
    var nextUrl = ""

    //func

    func refresh(){
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    @IBAction func plus(_ sender: NSButton) {
        if urlInput.stringValue == "" {

        } else {
        test_text = urlInput.stringValue
        test_data.append(test_text)
        urlInput.stringValue = ""
        tableView.reloadData()
        // fonction du bouton +
        }
    }

    @IBAction func nextLien(_ sender: NSButton) {
        if test_data == [] {

        } else {
        nextUrl=test_data[0]
        var monUrl = URL(string: nextUrl)
        var maRequete = URLRequest(url: monUrl!)
        view_web.load(maRequete)
        test_data.remove(at: 0)
        tableView.reloadData()
        //fonction du bouton pour le prochain lien
        }
    }

    func numberOfRows(in tableView: NSTableView) -> Int {
        return test_data.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: NSTableView, objectValueFor tableColumn: NSTableColumn?, row: Int) -> Any? {
        return test_data[row]
    }

    //var

    @IBOutlet weak var urlInput: NSTextField!

    @IBOutlet weak var view_web: WKWebView!

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: NSTableView!


    //func vitale

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let myURL = URL(string: "https://www.youtube.com")
        let myRequest = URLRequest(url: myURL!)
        view_web.configuration.preferences.plugInsEnabled = true
        view_web.load(myRequest)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }
}
```

What I don't understand, it's that the `viewtable.reloaddata()` works fine in the ViewController.swift file, but the same instruction doesn't work when I try to do it in the `AppDelegate` file.

I do have check that my array of strings (test_data) is not empty. (It contains 4 elements after I load and extract the data of a ".txt" file that I had created myself.)

I would like to know how could I fix this error so the data is shown in my TableView after I parse my txt file.

Thank you very much.

Comment: I would very strongly against storing a view controller in your app delegate. Sooner or later you're going to want to add support for multiple windows in your app, and it'll bite you in the ass

Comment: In the case of this project, I will keep it to a single window app, but I take good note for future projects... :)

Comment: Even still, it's not good practice. For one, it's causing your [chicken or egg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicken_or_the_egg) scenario where your app delegate loads after your vc,  vc is loaded by your app delegate. At the time that `openUnFichier(_ sender: NSMenuItem)` is called, your `vc` is initialized (as in, the object exists), but not loaded (as in, none of its constituent UI elements are initiated, and all of its `IBOutlet`s are `nil`)

Comment: @Alexander The problem I came across (that made me write the code in the AppDelegate file) is that I couldn't CTRL+Drag the Open... menu into my ViewController, but I could in my AppDelegate file...

Comment: Indeed, image what would happen if that weren't the case. If a menu item was bound to a view controller class, and there are multiple instance of that view controller class, which one of them should have their `@IBAction` triggered? What if there are no windows?  Menu items are tied to the app delegate, which is exactly for this: a delegate to handle events pertaining to your app. Its life cycle is tied to the application, unlike a view whose life is fundamentally tied to its parent window.

Comment: @Alexander I do get that point. But, where would you suggest me to write the code I wrote in AppDelegate? Maybe it could help to fix the issue I guess?

Comment: There are many issues in this code, but I think they're all rooted in the misunderstanding of view controllers, and how they're instantiated. When you tried to do this, you created a `vc` object, but you didn't create a window within which that vc will reside. You could manually create an `NSWindow` and manage all that yourself, but I would recommend using storyboard instead, which will both initiate an NSWindow, and its content vc. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/21231688/3141234 for a rough idea for how to handle menu items at an app level

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a simple solution: Move the `IBAction` to the view controller.

- In Interface Builder disconnect the `IBAction` from `AppDelegate`.
- Move the `openUnFichier` method to `ViewController` (delete it in `AppDelegate`).
- In Interface Builder connect the menu item to `First Responder` (the red cube) and choose `openUnFichier` in the list. The first class in the responder chain which implements the method will execute it.

Comment: Note that this will only work while the VC exists, and won't work if there are no windows. Given that `openUnFichier` means `open a file` (in french), it's quite likely that there are no windows at the time that it's used.

Comment: @vadian Euh... The two first points seems to be ok for me to do. But I don't get something in your last step... By default, the menu item is connect to First Responder, I think. But how could I choose openUnFichier? Is it like the dropdown menu when I create an Outlet for example?

Comment: I mean the First Responder above the menu bar in Interface Builder. A popup window is supposed to appear with all available selectors.

Comment: I did figure out the last step! Thank you very much! It as fix my problem. :)

Comment: @vadian It was the popup window with the selectors that I didn't know, but I figure it out. :)